# Typescript, Type-Inferance: How to make Typescript be able to suggest the name of the props of an object?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, mapped-types

Using RTK-query in React we've got a nice feature. Once we've defined the ApiSlice with it's endpoints RTK-query autogenerate hooks for us. Not only that, but Typescript is able to suggest what hooks are available to us.

I've tried to implement something like that with no luck.
This is my setup:

```js
interface Selector {
    findBy: (id: string, options?: any) => any
    id: string;
}

export interface Selectors {
    [key: string]: Selector;
}

type GettersWithUniqueName<Definitions extends Record<string, Selector>> = keyof Definitions extends infer Keys
    ? Keys extends string
    ? {
        [K in Keys as `get${Capitalize<K>}`]: () => any
    }
    : never
    : never;

declare const generateGetDOMElements: (selectors: Selectors) => (() => GettersWithUniqueName<Selectors>)
```

Later in my code I do something like this:

```js
const selectors: Selectors = {
  element1: {
    findBy: () => {}, // a function
    id: '' // a string
  },
  element2: {
    findBy: () => {}, // a function
    id: '' // a string
  }
}

const elements = generateGetDOMElements(selectors);
const getters = elements();
```

Now, as hard as I try, I can't find a way to let Typescript knows that `getters` will only have two members called `getElement1` and `getElement2`.

With this setup the only thing I've managed to get is that if I try to access a member of elements with wrong name pattern, Typescript will comply, like:

```js
getters.hello(); // error
getters.getBob(); // no error
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] to make your code a [mre] without third-party dependencies or unrelated errors?  (e.g., `Cypress`, `MatcherOptions`, `JQuery` implicit `any` errors, etc)  Unless of course the question actually *requires* these dependencies, in which case the question should probably be tagged with them to get the right eyes on it.  This will make it easier for us to get to work on the issue you are having without first spending time and effort on issues you're *not* having.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1keGm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (and one of us should [edit] the code in your question to use `any` or something instead of third-party things). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz WOW this is exactly what I need! Do you still need the edits in the question?

Comment: I can do it myself if you don't want to do it.  Presumably it would look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2kq8N).  Does that work?

Comment: Yeah! It works really well, if you make it as answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make `generateGetDOMElements()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the keys of the `selectors` parameter, so that the output can be written in terms of these keys.  Possibly something like this:

```
type GettersWithUniqueName<K extends string> = {
    [P in `get${Capitalize<K>}`]: () => any
}

declare const generateGetDOMElements:
    <K extends string>(selectors: Record<K, Selector>) => 
      (() => GettersWithUniqueName<K>);
```

I also simplified your `GettersWithUniqueName` to use just the keys  since that's all it cares about.

Now we can test it.  Note that if you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `selectors` as having type `Selectors`, you're throwing information the compiler needs, since `Selectors` has a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and doesn't know *which* keys are actually present.  You can just leave off the annotation and let the compiler infer its type, but if you really care about making sure it is compatible, you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```
const selectors = {
    element1: {
        findBy: () => { }, // a function
        id: '' // a string
    },
    element2: {
        findBy: () => { }, // a function
        id: '' // a string
    }
} satisfies Selectors;

const elements = generateGetDOMElements(selectors);    
const getters = elements();
// const getters: GettersWithUniqueName<"element1" | "element2">
    
getters.getElement1(); // okay
getters.getElement2(); // okay
getters.getRandomThing(); // error
getters.foo(); // error
```

Looks good.  The type of `getters` is `GettersWithUniqueName<"element1" | "element2">`, which expands to something like `{getElement1(): any, getElement2(): any}`, and the compiler can check and suggest keys as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoQDYQWA9lZAbwChkzkZQATAIQE8AuZACmCqYGcwpQBzAGmS4ADmGC4QHAPxM4IOgEpkAXgB8yOXVLk2nbnwDcxAL7FioSLEQp0WHPg5FtZANoBrCI2RceIXgF0mW2w8KCNTMzA6YRQAcQgwSw4AdWAwAAsAVRBgAEcAVwgAOTgAWwgAHgBpZAgAD0gQKkcfPnVlJ3JkFwAFZFBkAANeBIASQgBhOGE0uAxgAC9KqtVjQcCWJTUNeRMzKmwMOCgUBAkuZBGQaDhIeLAAEQB5AFkAUSxy8A4GZ2Rq2oNCBNFr6PyqZgcTAhBxMABK2HwVGqgmC9igqi26mYzCxyHuSVSGWyeUKJXK1UxRmIZ0kYG80PRjg6JC60K+YAAjExWV1yJQmvQmLiVOpCMhjIIAPRSjQUfIgHDiEB-Lq6ZAAcg1yBlctafj+kr+7OBYAATDzVfzqELNqKiBLpbK4PLFWIJFayOqtTrnd4wbxDSZvLdgBxKBBHGjQhxqbSLibvipLsCbncEs93p9TRxIYyYwo4+d6SNEtBmbVs99cUZdfGSwkkkwCeWiVkcgVimVKgAiRNcnvIAA+yD7VfNPdUZlLSQAdKWPhAOZya76hG44FoZ+X5wlFxyzavdbgN1vGzvS3C5FRcKUACrpPhH2XQKD4YjbqAcWcwXC4Z+1FAb5QEAA)